# How does a recursive method work?

Tags: haskell, recursion, runtime, typeclass, dependent-type

Consider the following method `count` that maps type level natural numbers to value level ones:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DataKinds
  , KindSignatures
  , PolyKinds
  , FlexibleInstances
  , FlexibleContexts
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  #-}


module Nat where

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Proxy (a :: k) = Proxy

class Count a where
    count :: a -> Int

instance Count (Proxy Z) where
    count _ = 0

instance Count (Proxy n) => Count (Proxy (S n)) where
    count _ = succ $ count (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

It seems to work in repl:

```
λ count (Proxy :: Proxy (S(S(S Z))) )
3
```

For the recursion to terminate, there must be some indication at run time of the type of the `Proxy`, but types are supposed to be erased at run time. I can even replace `data` with `newtype` in the `Proxy` definition:

```
newtype Proxy (a :: k) = Proxy ()
```

— Which would oblige it to have the same memory representation every time, so that it were `Coercible`. With that in mind:

1. I totally do not understand how a method gets dispatched. I would theorize that, either:

   - A table of form *(Type, Method name) ⟶ Function* is generated by the compiler. Then, at run time, all the objects are tagged with their type, and a method is a higher order function that looks at the type tag and looks up the corresponding function in the table. But people say types are completely erased during compilation, so this does not add up.
   - A table of form *Method name ⟶ Function* is attached to every object, and a method invocation is represented as *Method name*. Then, a function application looks up the corresponding *Function* and applies it when it is forced. To save space, the table may be shared by all the members of the type, but then it is no different from having objects tagged with type.
   - A table of form *(Method name, Instance index) ⟶ Function* is generated by the compiler, and tables of form *(Method name -> Instance index)* are attached to objects at run time. This means an object does not know its type, but knows the classes it belongs to, and the correct choice of instance. I do not know if there are any advantages to this approach.

   So, I do not understand how the run time system determines the right choice for the method instance if the objects are not tagged with their type in some way, direct or indirect. People all around are talking about some dictionary passing stuff, but I totally do not get it:

   - What are the keys?
   - What are the values?
   - Where does the dictionary reside? (On the heap, in the program text, still elsewhere?)
   - Who has pointers to the dictionary?

   ...Et cetera.
2. Even if there is a trick in place that allows for the choice of method instance without tagging objects with types, there are only 2 instances of `Count`, so the choice of a method may only carry 1 bit of information. (For example, there may be a `Proxy` with a tag that says *"apply methods from instance A<sub>1</sub> to me"*, and the method instance in A<sub>1</sub> retags the `Proxy` with *"apply methods from instance A<sub>0</sub> to me"*.) This is clearly not enough. There must be something at run time that ticks down every time the recursive instance is applied.

Can you walk me through the execution of this code, or throw in some links that describe the applicable particulars of the runtime system?

Comment: Nitpicking: Haskell has *no* methods, these are *functions* (there is some difference between a method and a function).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How do you call two function that share the name then?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem From the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3): "A class declaration introduces a new class and the operations (class *methods*) on it."

Comment: This method is not recursive!

Comment: @DanielWagner But it is *obviously* recursive. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Not at all: `count` doesn't call itself, it calls a *different function* that just happens to also be named `count`. e.g. `count @(S (S Z))` calls `count @(S Z)`; similarly `count @(S Z)` calls `count @Z` -- and these are three *different* functions.

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, this is a perspective from the low level where there are no classes, no methods, only functions. From a higher point of view, my opinion is that, if we think of it as a recursive method (for example, we arrange for a base case and a recursive case that gradually reduces the problem towards the base case), we may call it a recursive method. It just happens to compile down to something else, but this is not our primary care. (Before this question, I did not even know it does.) Do you have a specific objection to this kind of a "higher level" nomenclature?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov My mental model: a class is a collection of types, plus an implementation of the methods for each type in that collection. The collection that satisfies the `Count` constraint is recursively defined, but the methods are not: the implementation of the method for one type does not recurse back into its own implementation, but calls the method for another type in the collection. By analogy, `mempty = (mempty, mempty)` patently isn't recursive: the "recursive" calls to `mempty` behave very differently than the top-level one (and don't even have the same type!).

Comment: @DanielWagner Well, I now have not one, but two useful mental models! I take it to be a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type classes are desugared to records. Everything happens at compile time.

```
data Count a = Count { count :: a -> Int }

instance_Count_ProxyZ :: Count (Proxy Z)
instance_Count_ProxyZ = Count { count = \_ -> 0 }

instance_Count_ProxySn :: Count (Proxy n) -> Count (Proxy (S n))
instance_Count_ProxySn context = Count {
  count = \_ -> succ (count context (Proxy :: Proxy n)) }
```

Whenever we call `count :: Count n => n -> Int`, the desugarer (that runs after the typechecker) looks at the inferred type for `n`, and tries to construct a record of type `Count n`.

So if we write `count (Proxy :: Proxy (S (S (S Z))))`, we need a record of type `Count (S (S (S Z)))`, and the only matching instance is `Count (Proxy n) -> Count (Proxy (S n))`, with `n ~ S (S Z)`. This means we now have to construct its argument, of type `Count (Proxy (S (S Z)))`, and so on.

Note that this is also what happens in the process of desugaring the application of `count` in the instance for `Proxy (S n)`.

After this process there are no type classes left, everything is just records.

Comment: So it's kind of like Template Haskell? And I end up with a hard coded chain of functions?

Comment: It's a form of code generation like TH, but it's entirely type-directed and more integrated in the language. It also doesn't allow arbitrary code execution like TH does.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever a constraint turns up at the LHS of a function declaration, like

```
count :: (Count a) => a -> Int
```

it's as it were syntactic sugar for

```
count' :: CountDictionary a -> a -> Int
```

where `CountDictionary a` is a runtime-suitable (but singleton – the compiler always chooses exactly one instance for each type!) representation of, indeed, the *methods* of the `Count` class, i.e.

```
data CountDictionary a = CountDict {
         countMethod :: a -> Int
       }
```

Before I elaborate further, let me rewrite all without those ugly proxies in favour of `TypeApplications`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

class Count a where
    count :: Int
⇒ count' :: CountDictionary a -> Int
w/ data CountDictionary a = CountDict Int

instance Count Z where
    count = 0

instance ∀ n . Count n => Count (S n) where
    count = succ $ count @n
```

Now when you write `count @(S(S(S Z)))`, it's represented by

```
count @(S(S(S Z)))
  = count' ( CountDict (succ $ count @(S Z)) )
  = count' ( CountDict (succ $ count' (CountDict (succ $ count @Z))) )
  = count' ( CountDict (succ $ count' (CountDict (succ $ count' (CountDict 0)))) )
```

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Turns out a thing can be both ugly and popular! But less tongue-in-cheek: everybody used them historically because it is the cleanest known alternative to type applications if type applications don't exist, and type applications are a very new feature.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov They are not that ugly, but it is weird that in order to choose a compile-time type argument `a`, one needs to also pass a run-time value argument `Proxy :: Proxy MyChoiceForA`. A few years ago, we had no other choice, so proxies were a necessity. Now we got type application `@ MyChoiceForA` which is purely compile-time, and we no longer need proxies, making out code simpler and shorter. (Personally, I tolerated `Proxy a` arguments, and disliked the idiom `proxy a` where `proxy` is a higher-kinded type variable which might stand for `Proxy` but also for `[], Maybe, ...`.)

Comment: @chi Would this mean that `count` used to be a polymorphic function, but has become a constant applicative form?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov That's a good question, since at the point `count` looks as a CAF. Actually, it is not, because its full type is not `count :: Int` but `count :: Count a => Int` showing that, underneath, it is implemented as a function taking the count-dictionary.

Comment: @chi FTR, we did have a choice even in ye olden days: [`Tagged`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.8.5/docs/Data-Tagged.html), which I always found feeling less hackish than proxies – but it made code like this look even uglier. Luckily, `TypeApplications` are making all of this a thing of the past.

Comment: @leftaroundabout How is `Tagged` more suitable? As I understand, it has to carry an extra value, unnecessary in this case. Why would I write `Tagged () :: Tagged n ()` instead of just `Proxy :: Proxy n`?

Comment: @chi & leftaroundabout Also, if you could edit the post and add some references or ways to rediscover these details by hand — some kind of primary source, — it would be very helpful.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov no, not `Tagged ()`. You'd use `class Count a where count :: Tagged a Int`.